# How to implement "if" in normal order in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, lazy-evaluation, sicp

I was learning SICP and I read about "the applicative order" and "the normal order". Then I played around the Exercise 1-6 and looked into the following code:

```lisp
#lang racket
(define (p) (p))
(define (new-if test-expr then-expr else-expr)
  (cond (test-expr then-expr)
        (else else-expr)))
```

And when I evaluate `(new-if (= 2 2) 5 (p))` , it goes into a dead loop because both the `(= 2 2)` and `(p)` are evaluated. So I wonder how to make this `new-if` in the normal order without changing the `#lang racket` into `#lang lazy` , but I can't figure it out.

```lisp
> (new-if (= 2 2) 5 (p))
> 5
```

Comment: The whole *point* of exercise 1.6 is demonstrating that you can't make `if` as a normal function.

Comment: If you're using Racket to work through SICP, it's recommended to install the [sicp collection](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html) through the package manager and use [`#lang sicp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Language.html), btw.

Comment: The exercise asks you to explain why it can't work, not to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the evaluation order of `#lang racket`. `#lang lazy` works since it is normal order. You can delay evalution with `delay` / `force`:

```
#lang racket

(define (p) (p))
(define (new-if test-expr then-expr else-expr)
  (cond ((force test-expr) (force then-expr))
        (else (force else-expr))))
(new-if (delay (= 2 2)) (delay 5) (delay (p))) ; ==> 5
```

Without side effects you can replace `delay` with wrapping in a no argument lambda (thunk) and change `force` to apply the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If we define `new-if` as a function:

```
(define (new-if test-expr then-expr else-expr) 
   ...)
```

Then in the program

```
 (define (p) (p))
 (new-if (= 2 2) 5 (p))
```

the form `(new-if (= 2 2) 5 (p))` is a function call.

The functions call is evaluated in this order:

1. Evaluate `new-if`  (evaluates to our `new-if` procedure)
2. Evaluate `(= 2 2)` (evaluates to `true`)
3. Evaluate `5`       (evaluates to `5`)
4. Evaluate `(p)`     (leads to a loop)
5. Now the result of `new-if` is called with the arguments (the results from 2., 3. and 4.).

The problem is of course that we never get to 5. The evaulation of the `(p)` leads to an infinite loop *before* the body of `new-if` is evaluated.

This means, that no matter what we put in the body of `new-if` the call `(new-if (= 2 2) 5 (p))` will always lead to an infinite loop.

In order words, in a language with normal order semantics, you can't define `new-if` as a normal function.

The intended evaluation order of `(new-if e0 e1 e2)` is:

1. Evaluate `e0`, let's call the result `t`.
2. If `t` is non-false, then evaluate `e1`
3. Otherwise `t` is false, so evaluate `e2`
4. The result is the either the result from 2. or from 3.

This order of evaluation is different from the order in a function call. So `new-if` must defined as a new form. The mechanism to define forms that use non-standard evaluation orders is `define-syntax`. It allows you to define `new-if` as a macro.

Comment: I think that you have made a confusion between "Normal order" and "Application order". Am I right ? Because the normal order allows to define "new-if" as "if" but the application order does not. In normal order, the function substitutions are made before the arguments evaluation; in other word : fully expand then reduce.

Comment: @BenoîtFraikin Yes, I was thinking of the "normal" order Racket uses - and that's applicative order. I have edited the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So I wonder how to make this new-if in the normal order ...

You can't. `if` is a *special form* provided by the host Scheme environment you're running code in. Other conditional syntax like `cond` and `case` are derived from `if` via macros in most implementations, a topic that IIRC the book doesn't touch on either using in early chapters introducing Scheme or implementing in the interpreters and compilers it focuses on in later chapters.

The purpose of [exercise 1.6](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_thm_1.6) is demonstrating *why* `if` has to be special and can't be implemented as a normal function; Eva Lu Ator is wrong and the definition of `sqrt-iter` using her `new-if` is an example of how it can fail.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer**

As it is stated, the whole point of the exercise is too show that you cannot write `new-if` as a normal function if you use the application order evaluation. However the normal order evaluation permits it. So both order have advantages and drawbacks.

**More details**

The difference is that in the *application order evaluation*, you first evaluate all symbols (the function and the arguments) then you make the substitution, and in the *normal order evaluation*, you evaluation the first symbol (usually a function), proceeds to the substitution then evaluation again until you are reduced to a simple atom (a value).

So the application order evaluation can be seen as more efficient but you lacks a part of control.

**Example**

For example if you define `f` as

```
(define (f x) (* x x))
```

and you call `(f (+ 1 2))`, then the application order evaluation only computes a single time `(+ 1 2)`, when the normal order evaluation computes it twice :

1. `(f (+ 1 2))         % first call`
2. `(* (+ 1 2) (+ 1 2)) % f is substituted by its definition`

Since `*` is primitive, the computation is made with 2 instances of `(+ 1 2)`. So it is less optimal. There is a way to optimize this with laziness. The language Haskell uses laziness, and you can use it too in racket with `#lang lazy`. It is a normal order evaluation with a little addition (the laziness).

However the a normal order evaluation, it allows you to define

```
 (define (test x y) (if (= x 0) y 0))
```

since the expansion (the substitution of the function by its body) is made before the reduction (the computation that can leads to another evaluation of an expression).